# How to create a button in PDF BOX?

Tags: java, pdf-generation, pdfbox

I want to create a button in PDFBOX i.e., validate or reset button which will call some function of embedded javascript in PDF.

How can I create such button in PDFBOX?

I have tried following code with PDPushButton snippet but it is now working properly. Here when I click on button area, then tick mark symbol is displayed and toggles on every click. Also border is not getting displayed.
Instead I want to display normal button having label and border around it.

I`m using pdfbox version 1.8.10.

```
PDDocument doc = new PDDocument();
PDPage page = new PDPage();
doc.addPage(page);            

PDAcroForm acroForm = new PDAcroForm(doc);
        doc.getDocumentCatalog().setAcroForm(acroForm);

        PDActionJavaScript javascript = new PDActionJavaScript("function validate(index){ app.alert(index); }");
        doc.getDocumentCatalog().setOpenAction( javascript );

COSDictionary cosDict = new COSDictionary();
            COSArray rect = new COSArray();
            rect.add(new COSFloat(100));
            rect.add(new COSFloat(10));
            rect.add(new COSFloat(200));
            rect.add(new COSFloat(60));

            cosDict.setItem(COSName.RECT, rect);
            cosDict.setItem(COSName.FT, COSName.getPDFName("Btn")); // Field Type
            cosDict.setItem(COSName.TYPE, COSName.ANNOT);
            cosDict.setItem(COSName.SUBTYPE, COSName.getPDFName("Widget"));
            cosDict.setItem(COSName.T, new COSString("My Btn"));
            cosDict.setItem(COSName.V, new COSString("Validate"));
            cosDict.setItem(COSName.DA, new COSString("/Helv 7 Tf 0 g"));

            PDPushButton button = new PDPushButton(acroForm, cosDict);
            button.setValue("Validate Button");

            PDActionJavaScript tfJs = new PDActionJavaScript("validate("+index+");");
            PDAnnotationAdditionalActions tfAction = new PDAnnotationAdditionalActions();
            tfAction.setU(tfJs);
            button.getWidget().setActions(tfAction);

            PDGamma colourBlack = new PDGamma();
            PDAppearanceCharacteristicsDictionary fieldAppearance = 
                    new PDAppearanceCharacteristicsDictionary(cosDict);
            fieldAppearance.setBorderColour(colourBlack);
            button.getWidget().setAppearanceCharacteristics(fieldAppearance);

            page.getAnnotations().add(button.getWidget());

            acroForm.getFields().add(button);
```

Comment: I have tried with PDPushButton but I cannot set button text value here, also when I clicked on button tick mark symbol toggles.

Comment: I suggest you include your comment into the question (you can edit), and also include the code that you did. And mention what version you are using. (Hopefully, 1.8.10 or 2.0) Note that the call is not new PDPushButton, but PDFieldFactory.createField() and it is somewhat tricky.

Comment: I'm unable to see anything, although I found where it is (your code isn't self-working, document and pages are missing). Add this to your code: cosDict.setInt(COSName.FF, 65536); that is the flag for button.

Comment: new PDAppearanceCharacteristicsDictionary(cosDict) should be changed to new PDAppearanceCharacteristicsDictionary(new COSDictionary())

Comment: @Tilman Thanks for your suggestion about adding code cosDict.setInt(COSName.FF, 65536);
This worked but still facing issue for setting border of button.
new PDAppearanceCharacteristicsDictionary(new COSDictionary()) is not working.

Comment: But you still need to use fieldAppearance.setBorderColour(colourBlack); and button.getWidget().setAppearanceCharacteristics(fieldAppearance);

Comment: What I also did is  (at the beginning)       COSDictionary acroFormDict = new COSDictionary();
        acroFormDict.setBoolean(COSName.getPDFName("NeedAppearances"), false);
        acroFormDict.setItem(COSName.getPDFName("Fields"), new COSArray());
        PDAcroForm acroForm = new PDAcroForm(doc, acroFormDict);
        doc.getDocumentCatalog().setAcroForm(acroForm);

Answer (score 5):

Following code generated proper button with borders and also invokes javascript function properly.
Only issue is setting validate label on button.
If anyone have solution to it, please provide your feedback.

```
PDDocument doc = new PDDocument();
        PDPage page = new PDPage();
        doc.addPage(page);   

        COSDictionary acroFormDict = new COSDictionary(); 
        acroFormDict.setBoolean(COSName.getPDFName("NeedAppearances"), true);
        acroFormDict.setItem(COSName.getPDFName("Fields"), new COSArray());

        PDAcroForm acroForm = new PDAcroForm(doc, acroFormDict);
        doc.getDocumentCatalog().setAcroForm(acroForm);

        PDActionJavaScript javascript = new PDActionJavaScript("function validate(index){ app.alert(index); }");
        doc.getDocumentCatalog().setOpenAction( javascript );

        COSDictionary cosDict = new COSDictionary();
        COSArray rect = new COSArray();
        rect.add(new COSFloat(100));
        rect.add(new COSFloat(10));
        rect.add(new COSFloat(200));
        rect.add(new COSFloat(60));


        cosDict.setItem(COSName.RECT, rect);
        cosDict.setItem(COSName.FT, COSName.getPDFName("Btn")); // Field Type
        cosDict.setItem(COSName.TYPE, COSName.ANNOT);
        cosDict.setItem(COSName.SUBTYPE, COSName.getPDFName("Widget"));
        cosDict.setItem(COSName.T, new COSString("Btn"+1));
        cosDict.setItem(COSName.V, new COSString("Validate"));
        cosDict.setItem(COSName.DA, new COSString("/Helv 7 Tf 0 g"));
        cosDict.setInt(COSName.FF, 65536); 

        PDPushButton button = new PDPushButton(acroForm, cosDict);
        button.setValue("Validate Button");

        PDActionJavaScript tfJs = new PDActionJavaScript("validate("+1+");");
        PDAnnotationAdditionalActions tfAction = new PDAnnotationAdditionalActions();
        tfAction.setU(tfJs);
        button.getWidget().setActions(tfAction);

        PDGamma colourBlack = new PDGamma();
        PDAppearanceCharacteristicsDictionary fieldAppearance = 
                new PDAppearanceCharacteristicsDictionary(new COSDictionary());
        fieldAppearance.setBorderColour(colourBlack);
        button.getWidget().setAppearanceCharacteristics(fieldAppearance);

        page.getAnnotations().add(button.getWidget());

        acroForm.getFields().add(button);

         doc.save("/path");
         doc.close();
```

Comment: The reason for the missing text is (likely) that there is no appearance stream. That is a stream just like a content stream of a page, but that is used for the form object. The best would be to compare your file with another PDF file that has such a button (e.g. the file in https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/PDFBOX-2203 ) in PDFDebugger. The field is in object 51, the appearance stream is in object 52.

Comment: "12.7.4.2.2 Pushbuttons
A pushbutton field shall have a field type of Btn and the Pushbutton flag (see Table 226) set to one. Because this type of button retains no permanent value, it shall not use the V and DV entries in the field dictionary (see Table 220)."

Comment: @Tilman, I checked sample pdf for button at [issues.apache.org/jira/browse/PDFBOX-2203](http://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/PDFBOX-2203). After dubugging this PDF, I found that it is internally using field type Tx for textbox  instead of Btn for Button. And after modifying code as per this, solution is working.

Answer (score 3):

Here is the solution of "How to set caption for `PDPushButton` in PDFBox 2.0.0"

For caption value needs to show for `pushbutton`, you needs to call `setNormalCaption("captionStr")` of the `PDAppearanceCharacteristicsDictionary`.
Here is the code for Button Caption Value with text color change:

```
    PDDocument doc = new PDDocument();
    PDPage page = new PDPage();
    doc.addPage(page);

    try {
        COSDictionary acroFormDict = new COSDictionary();
        acroFormDict.setBoolean(COSName.getPDFName("NeedAppearances"), true);
        acroFormDict.setItem(COSName.FIELDS, new COSArray());

        PDAcroForm acroForm = new PDAcroForm(doc, acroFormDict);
        doc.getDocumentCatalog().setAcroForm(acroForm);

        PDActionJavaScript javascript = new PDActionJavaScript(
                "function validate(index){ app.alert(index); }");
        doc.getDocumentCatalog().setOpenAction(javascript);

        COSDictionary cosDict = new COSDictionary();
        COSArray rect = new COSArray();
        rect.add(new COSFloat(50));
        rect.add(new COSFloat(775));
        rect.add(new COSFloat(100));
        rect.add(new COSFloat(750));
        cosDict.setItem(COSName.RECT, rect);
        cosDict.setItem(COSName.FT, COSName.getPDFName("Btn"));
        cosDict.setItem(COSName.TYPE, COSName.ANNOT);
        cosDict.setItem(COSName.SUBTYPE, COSName.getPDFName("Widget"));
        cosDict.setItem(COSName.T, new COSString("ClickMe"));
        //cosDict.setItem(COSName.V, new COSString("Click Me"));
        cosDict.setItem(COSName.DA, new COSString("/F0 6 Tf 0 g 1 1 1 rg "));

        PDPushButton button = new PDPushButton(acroForm);

        PDActionJavaScript tfJs = new PDActionJavaScript("validate("+1+");");
        PDAnnotationAdditionalActions tfAction = new PDAnnotationAdditionalActions();
        tfAction.setU(tfJs);
        button.getWidgets().get(0).setActions(tfAction);

    //  button.setReadOnly(true);
        button.getCOSObject().addAll(cosDict);
        acroForm.getFields().add(button);

        PDAnnotationWidget widget = button.getWidgets().get(0);

        PDAppearanceCharacteristicsDictionary fieldAppearance = 
                new PDAppearanceCharacteristicsDictionary(new COSDictionary());
        COSArray borderColorArray = new COSArray();
        borderColorArray.add(new COSFloat((float) (141f/255f)));
        borderColorArray.add(new COSFloat((float) (179f/255f)));
        borderColorArray.add(new COSFloat((float) (226f/255f)));
        PDColor blue = new PDColor(borderColorArray, PDDeviceRGB.INSTANCE);
        fieldAppearance.setBorderColour(blue);
        fieldAppearance.setBackground(blue);
        fieldAppearance.setNormalCaption("Click Me");

        widget.setAppearanceCharacteristics(fieldAppearance);
        page.getAnnotations().add(widget);


        File file = new File("/path");
        System.out.println("File created");
        FileOutputStream fOut = new FileOutputStream(file);
        doc.save(fOut);
        doc.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Here:

```
cosDict.setItem(COSName.V, new COSString("Click Me"));
```

And here:

```
button.setValue("Click Me");
```

Will not work.

For this, you needs to add below line:

```
fieldAppearance.setNormalCaption("Click Me");
```

Above example is the solution for PDFBox2.0.
In PDFBox 1.8.11, i think this will also going to work. :)