# How to add button with "icon only" layout to pdf using PDFBOX?

Tags: java, pdfbox

How to add button with layout "icon only" to pdf using PDFBOX?
[create a button with this properties](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pC64Z.png)

I have try this [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32324074/19714479) before, but just can't set to the button properties I want.

[edit]

[This the button I created using acrobat.](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1rk1QW4tQlyVNLQ6xtvXGbSDgetpgrMT4/view?usp=sharing)

[And This the button i created using PDFBOX](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1mzNPODQNo-uKw_ASehZ9UGo1PC8O2Z1S/view?usp=sharing)

My question is in PDFBOX how to create a button similar to the button created in acrobat?

Comment: Please explain "but just can't set to the properties I want". Also consider linking to the file you created with PDFBox, and the file you created with Adobe.

Comment: @TilmanHausherr. I want to create a button exactly the same as the one created in acrobat, especially the layout properties to "icon only". here the [button created using acrobat](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1rk1QW4tQlyVNLQ6xtvXGbSDgetpgrMT4/view?usp=sharing). and this the [button created using PDFBOX](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1mzNPODQNo-uKw_ASehZ9UGo1PC8O2Z1S/view?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The desired layout information may be stored in the **TP** entry of the appearance characteristics dictionary:

| Key | Type | Value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| **TP** | integer | *(Optional; pushbutton fields only)* A code indicating where to position the text of the widget annotation’s caption relative to its icon: 0 No icon; caption only 1 No caption; icon only 2 Caption below the icon 3 Caption above the icon 4 Caption to the right of the icon 5 Caption to the left of the icon 6 Caption overlaid directly on the icon Default value: 0. |

*(ISO 32000-1, Table 189 – Entries in an appearance characteristics dictionary)*

Thus, you may want to try setting the **TP** entry of the `PDAppearanceCharacteristicsDictionary fieldAppearance` in the referenced code to **1**.

Comment: Thank you for answering my question. But I can't find COSName.TP in [pdfbox](https://pdfbox.apache.org/docs/2.0.12/javadocs/org/apache/pdfbox/cos/COSName.html). `COSDictionary cosDictButton = new COSDictionary();
        cosDictButton.setInt(COSName.TP, 1);
        PDAppearanceCharacteristicsDictionary fieldAppearance = 
                new PDAppearanceCharacteristicsDictionary(cosDictButton);`. is this how you do it? (PS. I'm still new to PDFBOX)

Comment: Then create a `COSName` instance for **TP** yourself. That class has constants for many names but not for all.